# How can i use lithuanian special letters in JAVA

Tags: java, encoding

I want to filter table and check string in selenium and that string in the web contains Lithuanian special letter so i get something like this "M?nesis" instead of "Mėnesis"

ElementsCollection activePlans = $$(".view-content .tile__title").filterBy(text("Mėnesis"));

How can i do that?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the wrong encoding is being used when you write the character to a file, the console, a database or whatever.  If the encoding / charset that is being used does not include a code for `U+0117`, then the encoder will often replace it with a `?`.

Comment: But how can i convert that string with correct encoding?

Comment: read this [definitive](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) guide by @balusc

Comment: You don't.  The string is probably correct.  The problem is the way you are outputting it.  You fix the problem by using the correct encoding when you output it.  (If your problem is what I think it is.  Unfortunately, there is no MVCE to allow us to be sure.)

Comment: But if i want to use it in checks for example I'm going to use Selenide.shouldHave, do i need to convert it?

Comment: Without an MVCE, we cannot advise further.